Show that $f(x_0+)= \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0, \varepsilon >0}f(x_0+\varepsilon)= \lim_{ h\rightarrow1, h>1 }f(hx_0)$
Let $f : (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (where $-\infty \leq a < b \leq \infty$) be a function and let $x_0 \in [a,b)$. Recall that the right limit of $f$ as $x$ approaches $x_0$ (wich I'm denoting here as $f(x_0+)$) is defined as follows:
$$ f(x_0+) = L\iff 
\left(\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists\,\delta>0,\text{ such that }\forall x\in(a,b):x \in (x_0,x_0 + \delta) \implies |f(x)-L|< \varepsilon\right)
$$
I'm almost right: $$f(x_0+)= \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0, \varepsilon >0}f(x_0+\varepsilon)= \lim_{ h\rightarrow1, h>1 }f(hx_0) \tag{1}$$
if $x_0 >0$
as Thomas emphasized in the comment below)
I've already managed to prove this: $$x_0 \in [a,b) \iff 0 \in \{\varepsilon >0 : x+\varepsilon \in [a,b)\}' \iff \{h> 1 : hx  \in [a,b)\}'$$ And therefore, the above limits are indeed well defined.
But I was unable to prove this equality (1). Could anyone help me with this?

Shouldn't it be $f(x_0h)$ rather than $f(xh)?$ Anyway, it is only true if $x_0>0.$

No, it should be $\lim_{h\to1; h<1}.$ Not to zero, for $x_0<0.$ Of course, if $x_0=0$ there is no solution.

You are right Thomas, I already fixed the errors. In the case where $x_0<0$
we would have to adjust the limit of $f(x_0h)$
to be $\lim_{h \rightarrow 1, h<1}f(hx_0 ) $ instead

Yes, that's what I meant.

By the way, the usual way to write these one-sided limits is $h\to1+$ and $h\to1-,$ or $h\to1^+, h\to1^-.$

There is no usual way, there is only a preferred one. Bourbaki, for example, uses the same notation that I am using in his book "Functions of a Real Variable" and "General Topology chapters 1-4"

There is definitely a usual way, in terms of frequency of usage.

You are just wrong by "usual way." There are outliers, but there is a usual notation, the one I've suggested.

What does $0 \in {\varepsilon >0 : x+\varepsilon \in [a,b)}' \iff {h> 1 : hx  \in [a,b)}'$ mean, please? And did you fail to prove both equalities of (1), or only the second one?

What stops you? Just notice (for $x_0>0$) that $$x_0<hx_0<x_0+\delta\iff1<h<1+\frac\delta{x_0}.$$

Both can be solved with a simple subsitution. We want to show
$$L = \lim_{x \to x_0^+}{f(x)} = \lim_{\epsilon_0 \to 0^+}{f(x_0+\epsilon_0)} = \lim_{h \to 1^+}{f(hx_0)}$$
(I added the "$_0$" to tell the epsilon apart from the $\epsilon$ in the limit definition, and changed to the conventional one sided limit notation as yours gets confusing)
Now our first limit defintion, $\lim_{x \to x_0^+}{f(x)}$, is $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that
$$ |f(x) - L| < \epsilon \quad \text{for all} \quad x \in (a, b) \quad \text{with} \quad 0 <x-x_0 < \delta$$
(a slightly differently worded, but equivalent, definition to yours)
For the first one let $x = x_0 + \epsilon_0$ . Then we have
$$ |f(x_0 + \epsilon_0) - L| < \epsilon \quad \text{for all} \quad x_0 + \epsilon_0 \in (a, b) \quad \text{with} \quad x_0 + \epsilon_0-x_0 = \epsilon_0 - 0 < \delta$$
which is $\lim_{\epsilon_0 \to 0^+}{f(x_0+\epsilon_0)}$
For the second one, let $x = hx_0$. Then
$$ |f(hx_0) - L| < \epsilon \quad \text{for all} \quad hx_0 \in (a, b) \quad \text{with} \quad hx_0-x_0 < \delta \Leftrightarrow h-1< \frac{\delta}{x_0}$$
which is $\lim_{h \to 1^+}{f(hx_0)}$. (And it can be seen therefore that $x_0 > 0$ is a necessary condition for the 2nd equality as otherwise we have $0 < h-1 < \frac{\delta}{x_0} < 0$)
